# How to get all photos in specific Facebook album?

Tags: php, facebook

Can I get all photo in specify Facebook album by Graph API like this?

```
$facebook->api( '[album_id]/photos' );
```

Currently it only return 25 results with paging.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try "[album_id]/photos?limit=100"

Answer (score 1):

You can, append ?limit=YOURLIMIT to that api call, but be sure it's not so high

Comment: Thank you! I've changed to use FQL :)